# JS/Reactjs - accessing a parameter passed from top level function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, variables, global

```
Box.expandBox(id);


var Box= (function(){
   return {
    expandBox: function(id) {
        console.log('inside expandBox: ' + id);
        ReactDOM.render( React.createElement(this.pBox(id)), document.getElementById('activate'))
    },
    pBox: function(id) {    
        console.log('inside pBox: '+ id);
        return React.createClass({
            getInitialState: function(id) {
                console.log('inside getInitialState: '+ id);
                return {
                    person_id: id
                }
            },

      ........
```

Trying to assign the state `person_id` to the `id` that is being passed externally. I got as far as outputting the data inside `pBox` but data is lost inside React's child function. I've tried doing the `var self = this` assignment but to no avail. I'm am lost at the scope when it comes to JS.

Comment: `getInitialState` does not even get passed any arguments, so should just leave it empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the `id` is shadowed by the argument of `getInitialState(id)` and becoming `undefined` because `getInitialState` is called without any arguments.

So, remove the argument and you can use the `id` provided in the `pBox` method in `getInitialState()`.

```
pBox: function(id) {    
    console.log('inside pBox: '+ id);
    return React.createClass({
        getInitialState: function() {
            console.log('inside getInitialState: '+ id);
            return {
                person_id: id
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `getInitialState` is expecting an argument for `id`. If it does not receive one, there still is an `id` in that local scope but it contains `undefined`. As mentioned by @Shuhei, removing that argument from the function or giving it a different name will allow you to access the `id` on a higher scope.

For readability's sake, I recommend you separate React.CreateClass into another function.

Your new function would look something like this:

```
function foo(id){
  console.log('inside pBox: '+ id);
  return React.CreateClass({...}) //Same code you had before
}
```

And your code would look something like this:

```
Box.expandBox(id);


var Box= (function(){
   return {
    expandBox: function(id) {
        console.log('inside expandBox: ' + id);
        ReactDOM.render( React.createElement(this.pBox(id)), document.getElementById('activate'))
    },
    pBox: foo

....
```